# i have installed jdk9 on my linux machine but jre file is missing, did i downloaded wrong tar file?

Tags: java, java-9

I have installed jdk9 on my linux machine but jre file is missing, did i downloaded wrong tar file?

this is the tar file i downloaded `jdk-9-ea+174_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Comment: In jdk, jre is in $JAVA_HOME/jre

Comment: jre file is missing in extracted jdk9 file thn how can i add jre path?

Comment: Where did you look for it?

Comment: inside extracted file is usually it exist there only

Comment: Why didn't you use your package manager? It's unusual to download on Linux manually. Only few programs should be downloaded manually (like Eclipse)

Comment: how it is useful?how to install it?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any problem with the tar file you have downloaded. There is a change in the directory layout with `JDK-9`. Until `JDK 8`, if you downloaded JDK, it contained the same `jre/` directory (which is separately available for download) plus some more tools and libraries. This resulted in duplicate binary files in bin directories of the JDK and the jre within JDK .
With `JDK 9`, there are no more `jdk/` versus `jre/` wrapper directories, and binaries (such as the java tool) are not duplicated. The `JDK` and `JRE` are two separate types of modular runtime images and both have the same directory structure containing the `bin`, `conf` and `lib` directories.Just that,JDK contains the compilation tool like `javac` as earlier.

Reference : [JDK 9 Migration doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-D867DCCC-CEB5-4AFA-9D11-9C62B7A3FAB1)

Comment: so shall i still set the jre path in bash?

Comment: What is your purpose? If it is development, then you can just set the path to JDK bin directory. If you need to just run applications , you can download the JRE and set the path accordingly.

Comment: actually i want to run tomcat but its nt running, may be due to the absence of jre file.

Comment: Is the version of Tomcat you are trying to run compatible with JDK 9 ? The documentation of Tomcat tells the versions it can run on.

Comment: @ZahidShah the documentation doesn't take Java 9 into account as it's not released. It wouldn't surprise me if at the moment no production version of Tomcat is Java 9 compatible. MAYBE the Tomcat 9 milestones will work, you'd have to try

Comment: @Pallavisonalyeah it says that tomcat9 requires java8 or later

Comment: As @jwenting said in his comment, even though documentation says JDK8 or later, it may not have taken JDK9 into account and may not be compatible with JDK 9.

Comment: able to install the tomcat now but could not change the tomcat port to 80, previously i used sudo with ./startup.sh to change the port 8080 to 80 it woorked but now whn i did run sudo ./startup.sh on tomcat9 it doesnt work.